# Stopwatch exception implementation in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, console

I'm new to C# programming and has been following a certain intermediate tutorial that has asked me to write a stopwatch simulation code that includes an exception system:

> ## Exercise 1: Design a Stopwatch
>
> Design a class called Stopwatch. The job of this class is to simulate a stopwatch. It should provide two methods: Start and Stop. We call the start method first, and the stop method next. Then we ask the stopwatch about the duration between start and stop. Duration should be a value in Timespan. Display the duration on the console.
>
> We should also be able to use a stopwatch multiple times. So we may start and stop it and then start and stop it again. Make sure the duration value each time is calculated properly.
>
> We should not be able to start a stopwatch twice in a row (because that may overwrite the initial start time). So the class should throw an InvalidOperationException is it's started twice.
>
> **Educational tip**: The aim of this exercise is to make you understand that a class should be always in a valid state. We use encapsulation and information hiding to achieve that. The class should not reveal its implementation detail. It only reveals a little bit, like a black box. From the outside, you should not be able to misuse a class because you shouldn't be able to see the implementation detail.

Transcribed from:

[image]

---

I have implemented code that does this exactly, however, I want to learn how to optimize my code to use fewer lines and make it more readable.

```
using System;

namespace Stopwatch_Training
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Stopwatch
        {
            private DateTime _startTime;
            private DateTime _stopTime;
            private TimeSpan _duration;
            public DateTime StartTime()

            {
                _startTime = DateTime.Now;
                return _startTime;
            }

            public DateTime Stoptime()

            {
                _stopTime = DateTime.Now;
                return _stopTime;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            int input1;
            DateTime starTime;
            DateTime endTime;
            double duration;
            int counter = 0;

            while (true)

            {
                Console.Write("1-Start Timer\n2-Stop Timer\n");
                input1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (input1 == 1)
                {
                    starTime = stopwatch.StartTime();
                    counter = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw (new InvalidOperationException("Please Start the timer with 1"));
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter '2' to stop the timer whenever you want");
                input1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (input1 == 2)
                {
                    endTime = stopwatch.Stoptime();
                    counter = 0;

                }

                else
                {
                    throw (new InvalidOperationException("Please end the timer with 2"));
                }
                if (counter == 1)
                {
                    throw (new InvalidOperationException("stuff"));
                }
                duration = (endTime - starTime).TotalSeconds;
                if (duration > 60.0)
                {
                    duration = (endTime - starTime).TotalMinutes;
                    Console.WriteLine(duration + "m");
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(duration + "s");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I have no idea how to implement an exception system in this case._ - Unfortuantelly _we_ cannot help you with that. Code Review is about improving working code, not about implementing missing features. You should read about how exeptions work first.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, but I found a similar post of the same issue at stack overflow, and they advised him to post it here (didn't find his post though).

Comment: You may want to look at the existing `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class for inspiration. Specifically its `Elapsed` and `IsRunning` properties, and the fact that none of its methods write anything to the console: that's not their responsibility, and it would add an unnecessary dependency which makes the class more difficult to reuse.

Comment: I have edited the post and added a new code that solves my question, however, I need help in optimizing my code to use fewer lines of code and perhaps improving its readability.

Comment: You can further improve the quality of your question by fully transcribing the image of the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the beginning of a stopwatch representation—you have its *data*. You still need to add its *behavior*.

Approach your design of the class as if the class should stand on its own. Input/output will be handled by something else, like the console, but the stopwatch should be the authority on its internal state.

The simplest stopwatch has a start/stop button and a display. We'll interpret "having a display" to mean "a way to get the stored elapsed time".

This means we'll need to provide three methods:

- **Start**: Sets the stopwatch in a *running* state.
- **Stop**: Sets the stopwatch in an *idle* state.
- **TimeElapsed**: Reads out the currently elapsed time.

Additionally, `Start` and `Stop` have the requirement that they should throw `InvalidOperationException` when the stopwatch is not a compatible state. Our stopwatch will need a notion of *running* to do this.

Let's look how we can modify the stopwatch class to adopt this behavior. I've annotated some below:

```
    public class Stopwatch
    {
        private DateTime _startTime; // we need this
        private DateTime _stopTime; // ? either this or duration
        private TimeSpan _duration;
        public DateTime StartTime() // why do we return a value here?

        {
            // we still need to check whether we are already running
            _startTime = DateTime.Now;
            return _startTime;
        }

        public DateTime Stoptime() // why do we return a value here?

        {
            // we still need to check whether we are still running
            _stopTime = DateTime.Now;
            return _stopTime;
        }

        // We still need the notion of 'currently running'
    }

    // First attempt
    public class Stopwatch
    {
        private DateTime _startTime;
        private DateTime _stopTime;
        private Boolean _running;

        public void StartTime()
        {
            if ( _running )
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot start: already running");
            }
            _startTime = DateTime.Now;
            _running = true;
        }

        public void Stoptime()
        {
            if ( !_running )
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot stop: not running");
            }

            _stopTime = DateTime.Now;
            _running = false;
        }

        public TimeSpan ElapsedTime()
        {
            if ( _running )
            {
                return DateTime.Now - _startTime;
            }
            else
            {
                return _stopTime - _startTime;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that we check if the stopwatch is currently running when asking for elapsed time: otherwise, we're going to get a very strange reading.

Now we can 'clean up' a little bit to follow conventions:

- Class members are implicitly private, so we don't need to add the `private` modifier.
- Members should start with a capital letter.

Which gives us:

```
    public class Stopwatch
    {
        DateTime StartTime;
        Boolean IsRunning;
        DateTime StopTime;

        public void Start()
        {
            if (IsRunning)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot start: already running");
            }
            StartTime = DateTime.Now;
            IsRunning = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (!IsRunning)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot stop: not running");
            }
            IsRunning = false;
            StopTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public TimeSpan ElaspedTime()
        {
            if (IsRunning)
            {
                return DateTime.Now - StartTime;
            }
            else
            {
                return StopTime - StartTime;
            }
        }
    }
```

And a quick Main to play around with it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        int choice;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("1-Start Timer\n2-Stop Timer\n3-Read Timer\n0-Quit\n");
            choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1: stopwatch.Start(); break;
                case 2: stopwatch.Stop(); break;
                case 3: Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElaspedTime()); break;
            }
        } while (choice != 0);
    }
```

Comment: You have really transcribe the text from the image? Respect ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t transcribinG iS morE fuN thaN televisioN ... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I implemented the solution, part of optimization I made StopWatach Class into a different file. Also made the Duration to be Displayed when both "Start" and "Stop" operations are performed.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("*** Welcome to my Stop Watch ***");

    var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    string choice;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. Start 2. Stop ");
        choice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case "start":
                stopWatch.Start();
                break;
            case "end":
                stopWatch.Stop();
                break;
        }

        if (!stopWatch._isRunning &&
            stopWatch._hasStopped) // Duration only prints when both start and stop Opeations are Completed 
            Console.WriteLine("Duration is: " + stopWatch.Duration());
    } while (choice == "start" || choice == "end" || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(choice));
}
```

and StopWatch.cs ,

```
public class StopWatch
{
    public DateTime _startTime;
    private DateTime _endTime;
    public bool _isRunning;
    public bool _hasStopped;

    public void Start()
    { 
        if (_isRunning)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already Started", new Exception("Stop Watch is already running"));

        _startTime = DateTime.Now;
        _isRunning = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (!_isRunning)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Start First", new Exception("Please Enter \"Start\" to start Stop Watch"));
        
        _endTime = DateTime.Now;
        _isRunning = false;
        _hasStopped = true;
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration()
    {
        var duration = new TimeSpan();
        duration = _endTime - _startTime;
        return duration;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you please [edit] to explain the benefit(s) of moving the StopWatach Class into a different file?

Comment: This is not a review.  It does nothing to help the original poster from OVER 5.5 YEARS AGO.  It is an alternative version.  Unless you can explain to the OP **WHY** your code is better, this does not help.